# how to use Multiple collection in Mybatis resultMap

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have three tables like A,B,C;it's my resultMap

```
<resultMap id="picUserResultMap" type="PicUserAlias">
<id property="id" column="ID"></id>
<result property="bindId" column="BINDID"></result>
<result property="createDate" column="CREATEDATE"></result>
<result property="pictureId" column="PICTUREID"></result>
<result property="picture" column="PICTURE"></result>
<result property="picDescribe" column="PICDESCRIBE"></result>
<result property="pictureNo" column="PICTURENO"></result>
<result property="userId" column="USERID"></result>
<collection property="picTypeUserList" ofType="picTypeUserAlias">
  <result property="userId" column="userid"></result>
  <result property="picTypeId" column="pictypeid"></result>
  <result property="content" column="content"></result>
  <result property="isTags" column="istags"></result>
</collection>
<collection property="picDiscussList" ofType="PicDiscussAlias">
  <result property="id" column="id"></result>
  <result property="discussUser" column="discussuser"></result>
  <result property="userId" column="userid"></result>
  <result property="picUserId" column="picuserid"></result>
  <result property="content" column="content"></result>
</collection>
```

it's my SQL query

```
<select id="getPicUserAndTypeById" resultMap="picUserResultMap">
SELECT
u.*, t.*,d.*
FROM
KO_PIC_USER u
LEFT JOIN (select tu.*,pt.istags from KO_PIC_TYPE_USER tu LEFT JOIN ko_pic_type pt on
tu.PICTYPEID=pt.ID WHERE pt.isshow=1) t ON t.PICUSERID = u.id
LEFT JOIN ko_pic_discuss d ON u.ID=d.PICUSERID
WHERE
u.BINDID = #{bindId} ORDER BY u.PICTURENO,t.istags
```

when I query out,the data was not accurate ,the picDiscussList like picTypeUserList 
I don't know why 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation about Advanced Result Maps](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html).
Both collections need an id, e.g: replace `<result property="picTypeId" column="pictypeid"></result>` with `<id property="picTypeId" column="pictypeid"/>`

Types `picTypeUserAlias` and `PicDiscussAlias` should not need userid and id property.